# Sampling random numbers from a distribution in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, sample, normal-distribution

I have a very simple code where I need to select 1 random number from a normal distribution, iterated ten times. My problem is I keep getting "NULL" instead of values.

```
n <- 1000 
Rnd <- rnorm(n,0,1)
Rnd
R <- data.frame(c(Rnd))
R
S <- list()

for (i in 10)
{
  S[[i]] <- R[sample(nrow(R),1, replace = TRUE),] 
}
```

This is the result I keep getting:

```
> S
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
NULL

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
NULL

[[10]]
[1] -0.364767
```

Please help!

Comment: Run `for (i in 10) { print(i) }` and this will show you the issue with your code. If you want to have 10 iterations, you need `for (i in 1:10) { print(i) }`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
n = 1000
Rnd <- rnorm(n,0,1) 

S <- x[sample(1:length(x),10,replace = F)]
```

You can change replace = T if you want numbers to be exclude from being resampled or not